# android updating UI with service in a separate process

Tags: android, user-interface, process, android-service

currently, I am using service to work in background and update UI periodically accordingly
That service is fired every 30 seconds
to avoid hanging UI requests....I specified a separate process for it, by adding the following.

```
android:process=":remote"
```

But, in that case, my UI stopped getting updated.
Need the resolution for this.

Comment: you can use thread in your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a *BroadcastReceiver* programmatically in your activity to get data back from the service and update the UI. You may also want to update the UI in your onResume() method in case the activity gets paused for any reason and then brought to front.

Don't forget you must update your views in the UI thread, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

If the service work is only relevant to the UI update, you may consider using a Timer/TimerTask or a Thread in the same activity in order to simplify the process.

**EDIT:** If you're working with webservices, consider using a single *AsyncTask* to perform all the work in *doInBackground(...)*, and update in *publishProgress(...)*

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am updating the UI in my onResume. Just need to periodically update data if user stands on the screen.

Comment: My service is doing 2 things - 1) firing web requests to get specific data, 2) updating UI with it.

Comment: Yes, I do have an asynctask in my Service and updating UI in onPostExecute

Comment: What you need to do is create the AsyncTask inside your activity. Create an infinite loop *while(true){}* and then fetch your data and update the UI every 30 seconds. Do it all inside your activity.

Comment: I am having a number of activities...in which I would like to get my data updated...So, should I use Asynctask in all of them?

Comment: No. But you haven't mentioned that before. I think the right choice is the Service and a broadcast receiver then. If sending the data serialized as an extra doesn't works for you, try sharing the data in the application object.

Comment: No, I guess, I don't need all this, as I am updating the data in the service, which goes well. and in onPostExecute of this, I am just calling the refresh function in my activity, which gets data from the db

Comment: But, now as I specified a separate process for my service, my UI isn't getting updated

Comment: So, all I need to update UI, from the service as a separate process

Comment: I got the solution with the help of this that what I want is not possible - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#IPC

Comment: Thanks to all for support.